# Chart control data points not visible - Visual WebPart

Tags: 2013, asp.net, visual-web-part, chart

I have created a Chart control based visual webpart. I have used custom labels for both x and y axis. The problem when i am trying to plot xy values, it is not visible in the chart.

[image]

**Code**

```
    chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
    chart1.Series["Series1"]["PointWidth"] = "0.6";

    foreach(string x in axisXValues)
    {
         clabelX = new CustomLabel(xpos, xpos + 1, x, 0, LabelMarkStyle.None);
         chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(clabelX);
         xpos++;
    }

    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        string c=r[0].ToString();
        string s=r[1].ToString();
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(c,s);
    }
```